# PHP replace string does not work

Tags: php, string

In my db a have this message MSG01:

```
"Availability between #DATA_MIN# - #DATA_MIN#"
```

Query:

```
select * from messages where MSG_CODE = "MSG01"
```

Column format is `VARCHAR(500)`.

I have this code to replace `#DATA_MIN#` and `#DATA-MAX#`:

```
$date = array($date->data_min, $date->data_max);
$replace_string   = array("#DATA_MIN#", "#DATA_MAX#");                                                                                                                 
$text= str_replace($replace_string,$date,  lang("MSG01")).
```

But on my site it appears like this: Availability between `#DATA_MIN#` - `#DATA_MIN#`. Why does it not replace the values?

Comment: Works fine here. Have you used a debugger to check the values for $date->data_min/data_max and lang("MSG01")?
Besides, I notice that the third line ends with a ".", not with a ";"

Answer (score 0):

You have one of two problems:

- Your site is not using `$text` from this example.
- Your `$date->data_min` property has the value `"#DATA_MIN#"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I've removed the # from DATA_MIN - DATA_MAX. It's working now.

Thank you, guys!